# Laravel Fortify login only if user is admin

Tags: laravel, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I have two table users and role and I need to log in using Laravel fortify only if user role is admin or showing error. I tried to do that using middelware, but i need to add the condition: If the user is not admin, he cannot log in.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In your answer, could you elaborate on your error, perhaps provide code example of what you have tried so far? [See minimal-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can read at laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#laravel-fortify-and-laravel-sanctum

```
Some developers become confused regarding the difference between Laravel Sanctum and Laravel Fortify
```

And:

```
If you are attempting to manually build the authentication layer for an 
application that offers an API or serves as the backend for a single-page 
application, it is entirely possible that you will utilize both Laravel Fortify 
(for user registration, password reset, etc.) and Laravel Sanctum (API token 
management, session authentication).
```

Then you want to check role of user, you should use [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)